# Collect for nonlinear terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Is there a way to expand `Collect`, so that it does not only separate equations by polynomial order, but by general nonlinear functions?

For example

```
expression = (2 + x + x^2 + x f[x] + x Sin[x]);
List@@Collect[expression, x]
```

results in `{2, x^2, x (1 + f[x] + Sin[x])}` instead of `{2, x, x^2, x f[x], x Sin[x]}`

My approach so far is to divide by the nonlinearity in question and check whether the denominator is one:

```
allTerms = List @@ expression
library = 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Times @@ # & /@ Tuples[{x^Range[0, 2], Times @@ # & /@ Subsets[{1, x f[x], x Sin[x]}][[2 ;;]]}]]
coeffs = Table[
  Total@Select[allTerms/element, (Denominator[#] == 1 \[And] FreeQ[#, x]) &]
, {element, library}]
```

I have a feeling there must be a better approach to it.

One obvious flaw of the code is that it won't work when there are denominators in the original expression.

I saw in the documentation that `Collect` can be used to extract terms by derivative order `D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + 1]], {x, 3}]; Collect[%, Derivative[_][f][_], Together]`. However, I am not sure how to apply this to my situation.

---

Update:

Thanks both to Omrie and Nasser for their answers. Both asnwers work perfectly on my test data set given. Unfortunately I realized that my example was overly simplified (each nonlinear term only occurred once and there were no other variables).

Here is an example that more closely resembles my problem:

```
expression = (2 + y + x + x^2 + x f[x,y] + x^2 f[x,y] + x Sin[x] + x y f[x,y] + y x^2);
List @@ Collect[expression, x]
```

resulting in `{2, y, x^2 (1 + y + f[x,y]), x (1 + f[x,y] + y f[x,y] + Sin[x])}` instead of `{2+y,x,x^2 (1 + y), x^2 f[x,y], (1 + y) x f[x,y], x Sin[x])}`

---

If `Collect` does not work, maybe one could use `Simplify` with a suitable `ComplexityFunction` or `ExcludedForms`?

Without additional options `Simplify` oversimplies things:
`Simplify[expression]` leads to `2 + x + x^2 + y + x^2 y + x (1 + x + y) f[x,y] + x Sin[x]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
expression = (2 + x + x^2 + x f[x] + x Sin[x]);
List @@ Collect[expression, _[x]]
```

which would yield the desired result

```
{2, x, x^2, x f[x], x Sin[x]}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of `_[x]`?

Comment: _[x] is a pattern object that can stand for any expression followed by [x]

Answer (score 1):

This should cover most cases:

```
List @@ 
  Collect[expression,
    Select[#, ! FreeQ[#, x] &] & @
      DeleteDuplicates @ 
        MonomialList[expression] /. z_Times :> Select[z, !FreeQ[#, x] &]
  ]
```

There is also a more general function available [here](https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcBook/ref/Collect2.html)

Comment: Could you elucidate on `/. z_Times :> Select[z, ! FreeQ[#, x] &]` please? Especially `z_Times` and `:>`. Leaving out `Times` or replacing `:>` by `->` does not work anymore.

Comment: No. Please just read https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/32-patterns.html and similar introductions.